# What does 'to rip into' mean

Tags: word-meaning

What does 'to rip into' mean in the following sentence?

> Georges Haussman *ripped into* poor neighborhoods, replacing them with
>   museum, apartments for the bourgeoisie, brownstones, architectural
>   wonders, wide and straight boulevards, etcetera.

Comment: What dictionary definitions did you look at?

Comment: Hello,@victoria, and welcome to ELL! This is a Q&A website for English learners; however, the site's guideline says "Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup (these are off topic on ELL, and there are many free dictionaries available online)", which makes your question off-topic. Please don't get discourage. We wish to see more good questions coming from you!

Comment: This reads like a very poor translation from the german "einreißen" which means "to tear down" in the case of buildings.

Comment: The usage is in a figurative manner. If you'd notice, Haussman ripping into poor neighborhoods is literally impossible. It is his power that does the ripping into. to rip into is to cut open/tear apart (hack and slash, [let me see what's within, maybe an intestine l.o.l.], something like that) But since the usage is figurative, the essence is more on the destruction that the action 'rip into' creates (sorry for the oxymoron)

Answer (score 1):

We often use "rip into" and "tear into" in American English to express the idea of rapacious hunger.

**Man, you really ripped into that t-bone steak.**

So this verb would suggest that Haussman did not selectively demolish the odd building here and there but aggressively razed entire neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

[Rip into](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rip+into) is an idiom used metaphorically in this case.

> 1. Lit. to attack someone or something by ripping.
>
> *The raccoons ripped into the trash bags, scattering papers and stuff all over the street. The horrid murderer ripped into the helpless
>   victim.*

The extract is saying that Haussman attacked poor neightbourhoods, destroying the area.

Comment: It should be clarified that this is a metaphor... he did not literally attack the neighborhood, more likely from the context it sounds like Haussman was a wealthy businessman funding new properties to be built over neighborhoods. The author is expressing that in a somewhat negative light by using the phrase "rip into."